# Need to change header/footer font in Excel 2002

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

How do you change the font type/size of the header and footer in Excel 2002?  I can't seem to find a way to do this in any of the menus.  At the very least I would like to make the header font smaller so the rest of my sheet fits correctly without the header overlapping the first row of my sheet.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Make sure you have the text you want to change the font size on highlighted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click on **View ---> Header & Footer**
2. Click on **Custom Footer** or **Customer Header**
3. Now you should see a **Font Icon** that you can click to change size and font type